# SharePoint 2013 API - get only newly modified list items

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I'm currently using this REST service to retrieve list items:

```
_api/lists/getbytitle('List Title')/items?$oderby=DueDate
```

Is it possible to use some query parameter to filter the items newer/older than a specific date, using the standard `Modified` date field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself: using the `$filter` parameter with OData expression

```
/items?$filter=Modified gt datetime'2014-11-27T12:00:00.000Z'
```